# API Issue - Authorization & Mount of Endurance Storage Issue

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

1.We are a part of DST India team and currently we are working for an offering for our client where we authorize Virtual machines to trying to integrate performance and endurance storage features (of SoftLayer) in ICO using REST API provided by SoftLayer. But during authorization of virtual machines to Endurance storage, we are getting intermittently a issue which is "Softlayer_Network_Storage_Netapp_Volume_Container::allowAccessFromHostList is not implemented".
The rest call we are using is "https://username:Key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/StorageID/allowAccessFromHostList.json"

& the post method we are using is

```
{"parameters":[[{"id":VirtualMachineRuntimeID,"objectType":"SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"}]]}
```

The virtual machine is not getting authorized to the endurance storage intermittently. Please look into this matter.

2. Another problem we are facing while mounting specially for Virtual machine with OS version RHEL 6.7 . Here, we have made an automated process to mount the virtual machines after authorizing it to performance & endurance storage.
   Its getting authorized but intermittently, its not getting mounted. For the process we have created shell script from the link you have provided in softlayer, it's added here for your reference "http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/block-storage-linux".
   For your information, this issue we are getting specially for the VMs which are authorized to Endurance Storage.

Please look into this matter and if necessary provide us additional details regarding the mount process which we are missing.Also, kindly provide any other additional details regarding mount process.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not customer support for SoftLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccessFromHostList](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList), I was not able to reproduce the exception that you got, I tried several times but it works fine.

You can submit a ticket for further assistance. However you can use: [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccessFromVirtualGuestList](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromVirtualGuestList) method that allow access for virtual guests.

Regarding to **Mount of Endurance Storage Issue**, did you see this particular issue with a specific endurance? or did you have the same issue for others (endurance storages)?

Comment: We have already raised ticket there in softlayer, but they said to post this API question in Stackoverflow, thats why i have posted here only.

Comment: Regarding to Mount of Endurance Storage Issue, we have got the issue with other storage (endurance storage) also. Is it Virtual machines problem or storage issue?? This is issue is happening irregularly.

Comment: Attach this forum to the ticket, in order that they can bring assistance with development team